storedPaymentMethods POST method not working in Adyen
I am using Adyen as a payment integration method. To store card and get token for further payment. I am trying to call https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v71/storedPaymentMethods API but getting "000 Service storePaymentMethods not present" in response. I am following https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/Checkout/71/post/storedPaymentMethods document, call request of this API is not seen in account API logs where as other API's call gets listed.
Below is the CURL:
curl --location --request POST 'https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v70/storePaymentMethods' \ --header 'X-API-key: KEY' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{ "merchantAccount":"merchantAccount", "shopperReference":"Shopper reference", "paymentMethod":{ "type":"scheme", "encryptedCardNumber":"test_4111111111111111", "encryptedExpiryMonth":"test_03", "encryptedExpiryYear":"test_2030", "encryptedSecurityCode":"test_737", "holderName":"name" }, "recurringProcessingModel":"UnscheduledCardOnFile" }'
I am not sure what is missing or did need to add any permission from account to get API been called.
Want to add that GET method of storePaymentMethods is working and gives proper outcome.

There is a mistake in the endpoint url: it is https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v70/storedPaymentMethods (instead of storePaymentMethods).
